# Trouble packaging MapsDemo

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am a complete newbie to MonoDevelop and any mobile device development for that matter.

I have just downloaded and installed monodevelop for android (Windows trial edition) and all the other things that come with it (Java, Android SDK, GtkSharp, etc).  I was able to make a few basic apps and deploy them on an emulator.  Then I downloaded the sample applications.  I want to make the MapsDemo but am having problems getting it deploy.

I think I have made a new AVD that is targeted to Google APIs (Platform 2.3.3 API Level 10)
When I try to run the app using Run|Run With|Android Device emulator-5554 I get a bunch of errors resulting in a "Package creation failed."

The following are the first few errors:

```
  AddOnPlatformLibraries:



C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javac.exe -d obj\Debug\android\bin\classes -classpath "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\mono.android.jar" -bootclasspath "C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxxxx\Local Settings\Application Data\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar" -encoding UTF-8 "@C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxxxx\Local Settings\Temp\tmp14A.tmp" 



obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\maps\ItemizedOverlay_OnFocusChangeListenerImplementor.java(8,42): javac error :  package com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay does not exist

obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\maps\ItemizedOverlay_OnFocusChangeListenerImplementor.java(8,42): javac error :       com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.OnFocusChangeListener

obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\maps\ItemizedOverlay_OnFocusChangeListenerImplementor.java(8,42): javac error : 



obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\maps\ItemizedOverlay_OnFocusChangeListenerImplementor.java(27,53): javac error :  package com.google.android.maps does not exist
```

I would appreciate any help.  Remember, I am completely new to this.

Comment: Are you referencing `Mono.Android.GoogleMaps` in the application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be targeting an AVD with a Target API of Google APIs. See this image for details http://snag.gy/tIPoW.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you followed the steps here: [Creating a device with Google Maps support](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsDemo#creating-a-device-with-google-maps-support)

Then what I did was to change the Android Target to Android 4.0 for MWC.Core.MD and MWC.Droid (Project Properties->Application->Minimum Android to target) and then reloaded the solution.

Compilation problems just went away after doing this. I assume that by changing the target, the reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.0\Mono.Android.GoogleMaps.dll was added.